# Running an external python script from maven

Tags: java, python, eclipse, maven

I have to run a run a python script from a maven project. I created a temporary class with main method to check if it works as expected, used the process builder and it works if I specify the absolute path of the python script and then run the java class from eclipse using RUN as Java application.

If I change it getClass().getResourceAsStream("/scripts/script.py"), it throws an  exception as it cannot locate the python script.

What would be the best place to place the python script and how can I access it in the Java class without specifying the complete path. Since I am new to maven, it could be due to the method used to execute the Java program.

```
package discourse.apps.features;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;  
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;



public class Test {

protected String scriptPath = "/Users/user1/project1/scripts/script.py";
protected String python3Path = "/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/python3/bin/python3";


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Test().score();
}

public JSONObject score() {
        String text1="a";
        String text2="b";
        JSONObject rmap =null;  

        try
        {

        String line= null;  
        String writedir=System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "/Tmp";
        String pbCommand[] = { python3Path, scriptPath,"--stringa", text1, "--stringb",text2,"--writedir", writedir };
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(pbCommand);
        Process p = pb.start();

            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
                rmap= (JSONObject) parser.parse(line);
            }

        } catch (IOException | ParseException ioe) {
            System.err.println("Error running  script");
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return rmap;
    }
}
```

Here is the output from pb command
pbCommand[0]:/Users/user1/.virtualenvs/python3/bin/python3

pbCommand[1]:displays the complete python script

```
import os,sys
from pyrouge import Rouge155
import json
from optparse import OptionParser

def get_opts():
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("--stringa", dest="str_a",help="First string")
    parser.add_option("--stringb", dest= "str_b",help="second string")
    parser.add_option("--writedir", dest="write_dir", help="Tmp write directory for rouge")

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    if options.str_a is None:
        print("Error: requires string")
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(-1)

    if options.str_b is  None:
        print("Error:requires string")
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(-1)

    if options.write_dir is  None:
        print("Error:requires write directory for rouge")
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(-1)    

    return (options, args)

def readTextFile(Filename): 
        f = open(Filename, "r", encoding='utf-8')
        TextLines=f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return TextLines

def writeTextFile(Filename,Lines): 
        f = open(Filename, "w",encoding='utf-8')
        f.writelines(Lines)
        f.close()

def rougue(stringa, stringb, writedirRouge):
    newrow={}
    r = Rouge155()
    count=0
    dirname_sys= writedirRouge +"rougue/System/"
    dirname_mod=writedirRouge +"rougue/Model/"
    if not os.path.exists(dirname_sys):
        os.makedirs(dirname_sys)
    if not os.path.exists(dirname_mod):  
        os.makedirs(dirname_mod)
    Filename=dirname_sys +"string_."+str(count)+".txt"
    LinesA=list()
    LinesA.append(stringa)
    writeTextFile(Filename, LinesA)
    LinesB=list()
    LinesB.append(stringb)
    Filename=dirname_mod+"string_.A."+str(count)+ ".txt"
    writeTextFile(Filename, LinesB)
    r.system_dir = dirname_sys
    r.model_dir = dirname_mod
    r.system_filename_pattern = 'string_.(\d+).txt'
    r.model_filename_pattern = 'string_.[A-Z].#ID#.txt'
    output = r.convert_and_evaluate()
    output_dict = r.output_to_dict(output)
    newrow["rouge_1_f_score"]=output_dict["rouge_1_f_score"]
    newrow["rouge_2_f_score"]=output_dict["rouge_2_f_score"]
    newrow["rouge_3_f_score"]=output_dict["rouge_3_f_score"]
    newrow["rouge_4_f_score"]=output_dict["rouge_4_f_score"]
    newrow["rouge_l_f_score"]=output_dict["rouge_l_f_score"]
    newrow["rouge_s*_f_score"]=output_dict["rouge_s*_f_score"]
    newrow["rouge_su*_f_score"]=output_dict["rouge_su*_f_score"]
    newrow["rouge_w_1.2_f_score"]=output_dict["rouge_w_1.2_f_score"]
    rouge_dict=json.dumps(newrow)
    print (rouge_dict)


def run():
    (options, args) = get_opts()   
    stringa=options.str_a
    stringb=options.str_b
    writedir=options.write_dir 
    rougue(stringa, stringb, writedir)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

pbCommand[2]:--stringa

pbCommand[3]:a

pbCommand[4]:--stringb

pbCommand[5]:b

pbCommand[6]:--writedir

pbCommand[7]:/users/user1/project1/Tmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the script in the main/resources folder it will then be copied to the target folder.
Then make sure you use something like the com.google.common.io.Resources class, which you can add with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-io</artifactId>
    <version>r03</version>
</dependency>
```

I then have a class like this which helps to convert resource files to Strings:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.Resources;

public class FileUtil
{

    public static String convertResourceToString(URL url)
    {
        try
        {
            return Resources.toString(url, Charsets.UTF_8);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static String convertResourceToString(String path)
    {
        return convertResourceToString(Resources.getResource(path));
    }

    public static String convertResourceToString(URI url)
    {
        try
        {
            return convertResourceToString(url.toURL());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Some advice if you are learning maven try using it instead of the IDE to run and package your application, that is what it is suppose to do. Then once you are confident that the application will function as a packaged jar then just use the IDE to run it.

Comment: Actually this is a big maven project and I am just trying to run a separate class that has a  main function to test a functionality. I added the script to the resources folder and if I debug the whole script changed to a string but  the process builder does not consider this as an executable python script and it throws an ecxeption

Comment: Can you print out the pbCommand[]  or what is actaully executed in the process builder, I would suggest doing "\""+scriptPath+"\"" in pbCommand[]. Also you should try executing a script which is in your path variable, and try using this class to printout your script to verify it is in the correct location.